# How do I increase MIDI synth volume/gain without distortion on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-audio, midi

I'm playing back MIDI files on iPhone using a `MIKMIDISynthesizer` from [this library](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI). Unfortunately, the volume is very low, even when turning iPhone's system volume all the way up. To increase it further, I tried these things:

- modify all MIDI *Note On* event's velocity property to the maximum of 127. This slightly but insufficiently raises the volume.
- Add a *mixer node* to the `AUGraph` as described [here](http://www.deluge.co/?q=core-audio-mixers-master-volume-ios). This sufficiently raises the volume, but instantly distorts the signal so badly that the quality is way too poor.
- Raise the volume of the soundfont's samples using a soundfont editor like *Polyphone*. This has no perceivable effect.

Right now I'm running out of options. Is there any additional parameter or level (like `AVAudioSession` or `CoreMIDI`, maybe) that I've missed and provides the possibility to adjust volume/gain? Or MIDI commands that do the same?

---

### Code Snippets

**1. Using a mixer node**

This is the portion of `MIKMIDISynthesizer` that I modified in order to control the volume with a mixer node.

```
- (BOOL)setupAUGraph
{
    AUGraph graph;
    OSStatus err = 0;

    // 1. Create new AUGraph
    if ((err = NewAUGraph(&graph))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    // 2. Create output node
    AudioComponentDescription outputcd = {0};
    outputcd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    outputcd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;

    outputcd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    AUNode outputNode;
    if ((err = AUGraphAddNode(graph, &outputcd, &outputNode))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add ouptput node to graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    // 3. Create the instrument node
    AudioComponentDescription instrumentcd = self.componentDescription;
    AUNode instrumentNode;
    if ((err = AUGraphAddNode(graph, &instrumentcd, &instrumentNode))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add instrument node to AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    if ((err = AUGraphOpen(graph))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to open AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    AudioUnit instrumentUnit;
    if ((err = AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, instrumentNode, NULL, &instrumentUnit))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to get instrument AU unit: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    // 4. Create the mixer node
    AUNode mixerNode;
    AudioComponentDescription cd = {};
    cd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    cd.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Mixer;
    cd.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_MultiChannelMixer;

    if ((err = AUGraphAddNode(graph, &cd, &mixerNode))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add mixer node to AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    if ((err = AUGraphNodeInfo(graph, mixerNode, 0, &_mixerUnit))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to fetch mixer node reference from AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    UInt32 busCount = 2;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(_mixerUnit,
                               kAudioUnitProperty_ElementCount,
                               kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                               0,
                               &busCount,
                               sizeof (busCount)
                               );

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to set mixer unit properties");
        return NO;
    }

    // 5.1 Connect the instrument node as the mixer node's input
    if ((err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, instrumentNode, 0, mixerNode, 0))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect input node and mixer node: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    // 5.2 Connect the mixer node as the output node's input
    if ((err = AUGraphConnectNodeInput(graph, mixerNode, 0, outputNode, 0))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to connect input node and mixer node: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    if ((err = AUGraphInitialize(graph))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to initialize AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    // 6. Finally, start the graph
    if ((err = AUGraphStart(graph))) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to start AU graph: %@", @(err));
        return NO;
    }

    self.graph = graph;
    self.instrumentUnit = instrumentUnit;

    return YES;
}
```

After setting up the mixer node, I can change the volume like so (**introduces clipping!**):

```
-(void) setVolume: (float) volume {
    AudioUnitSetParameter(_mixerUnit, kMultiChannelMixerParam_Volume, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, volume, 0);
}
```

---

**2. Changing MIDI Events**

The second approach sets the `velocity` property of every Node On event to the maximum of 127. It increases the volume without any noise, but only to a certain level. Code resides within `MIKMIDINoteEvent`:

```
+ (MIKMIDINoteOnCommand *)noteOnCommandFromNoteEvent:(MIKMIDINoteEvent *)noteEvent clock:(MIKMIDIClock *)clock
{
    MIKMutableMIDINoteOnCommand *noteOn = [MIKMutableMIDINoteOnCommand commandForCommandType:MIKMIDICommandTypeNoteOn];
    noteOn.midiTimestamp = [clock midiTimeStampForMusicTimeStamp:noteEvent.timeStamp];
    noteOn.channel = noteEvent.channel;
    noteOn.note = noteEvent.note;
    noteOn.velocity = 127; // <------- Here's the magic
    return [noteOn copy];
}
```

Comment: What kind of distortion do you hear the mixer node add?  Did you try raising the volume less using the mixer node?

Comment: Yes I've tried setting the volume to 1.0 (everything as usual), 1.5, 2, 5... the distortion is hard to describe, a kind of crackling/rustling, but it happens at decent volumes already (e.g. 1.5), which does not happen if you just increase the Note On velocity for example (resulting in same volume though).

Comment: Are you aware that you can easily play MIDI files with AVAudioEngine?

Comment: Any chance you could post the code you're using? I'm the developer of MIKMIDI and haven't seen this issue before (I too am working on an iOS app using MIKMIDI for playback as we speak, in fact).

Comment: @matt Right now I don't see any advantage of `AVAudioEngine` as it just groups `AVAudioNode` objects, but thanks for bringing my attention to it.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen Hey Andrew, thanks a lot for participating :) I added my code above. Very well written framework, by the way.

Comment: I think @hotpaw2's answer is likely what's going on. My point was that this is not a problem inherent to MIKMIDI, and you should probably try to fix the root cause instead of hacking around it. Have you tried a different soundfont? Also, FWIW, the `-[MIKMIDISequencer modifiedMIDICommandsFromCommandsToBeScheduled:forCommandScheduler:]` method is provided exactly so that you can modify notes, on the fly. We use it to dynamically change velocity. That would be better than modifying MIKMIDI source code. Feel free to email me if you want to talk further (my contact link is in the MIKMIDI README).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out. My `AVSession`'s category was set to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` because I was also utilizing the microphone, which automatically outputs all audio over iPhone's small ear speaker at the top. This is why it appeared so quiet. In order to route the output to the main speakers, you have to call

```
[session overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&err];
```

Nonetheless thank you all for the troubleshooting, I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that was it for me too. The volume was fine on iPad, but not on iPhone and after having tried a lot of volume configuration settings, I finally found this answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

This can happen for certain types of sampled waveform used by MIDI synths.  The peak volume of a sampled waveform might already contain samples near or at the max possible for the format (e.g. +-32767 for 16-bit samples, or +-1.0 for float samples), even though the average volume (energy sum) is too low.  Any simple linear increase in volume will thus create clipping noise which can sound quite bad.

Various compressor techniques or filters might be able to increase the average volume without clipping, but that can add a quality reducing (but less annoying than clipping) distortion of its own.

Added: Using another midi sampler, sound font, or voice that has a near constant volume (lower PAPR, peak to average power ratio) is another possibility.

Comment: That is a perfect explanation for exactly the kind of noise I hear, thank you. +1, but not accepted as answer since it does not solve the problem yet.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Just tried 3 different soundfonts with the same result, unfortunately. I'll keep digging.

Comment: Try a near constant volume voice, some organ stops might be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with setting up an AVAudioSession with SampleRate which is equal to 44100.0 Hertz?

Comment: Well yes, I think 44100.0 Hz is default and at some point a session is initialized. I don't think the session is connected to the problem though.